# Theorem 1.20b in Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis

Tags: real-analysis

I have a question about the proof for Theorem 1.20b in Rudin's *Principles of Mathematical Analysis.*

Theorem 1.20 states:

(a) If $x\in \mathbb{R}$, $y\in \mathbb{R}$, and $x>0$, then there is a positive integer $n$ such that $nx>y$.

(b) If $x\in \mathbb{R}$, $y\in \mathbb{R}$, and $x<y$, then there exists a $p \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $x<p<y$.

The proof of (b) in the textbook is given below:

Since $x<y$, we have $y-x > 0$, and (a) furnishes a positive integer $n$ such that $n(y-x)>1$. Apply (a) again, to obtain positive integers $m_1$ and $m_2$ such that $m_1 > nx$ and $m_2 > -nx$. Then

$-m_2 < nx < m_1$.

Hence there is an integer $m$ (with $-m_2 \leq m \leq m_1$) such that

$m-1 \leq nx < m$.

If we combine these inequalities, we obtain

$nx < m \leq 1+nx < ny$.

Since $n>0$, it follows that $x< \frac{m}{n} < y$. This proves (b), with $p=\frac{m}{n}$.

I was wondering if this much shorter approach to proving (b) would also be correct:

Since $x<y$, we have $y-x > 0$, and (a) furnishes a positive integer $n$ such that $n(y-x)>1$. Rearranging, we obtain $y> \frac{1+nx}{n}$. Also, notice that $x = \frac{nx}{n} < \frac{1+nx}{n}$. So we choose $p=\frac{1+nx}{n}$, hence proving (b).

(Forgive me if I jumped to any illogical assumptions in my proof)

Comment: Maybe you are searching a proof like [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/930550/can-the-proof-of-theorem-1-20-b-in-the-book-the-principles-of-mathematical-an/950307#950307)

Answer (score 3):

You want the number to be rational. This is not guaranteed by taking $p=\dfrac{1+nx}n$. Note that the $m$ in Rudin's proof is really $\lfloor nx\rfloor+1$, if I am reading things correctly. This is basically what you did, but the floor ensures the number is rational.