# Theorem 1.20 (b) in Baby Rudin: Can the proof of the theorem be improved?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-writing, solution-verification

I'm reading *Principles of Mathematical Analysis*, third edition, and am at Theorem 1.20(b), which is as follows:

> If $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $y \in \mathbb{R}$, and $x < y$, then there exists a $p \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $x< p < y$.

Now here is the proof given by Rudin:

> Since $x<y$, we have $y-x > 0$, and Theorem 1.20(a) furnishes a positive integer $n$ such that $$n(y-x) > 1.$$ Apply Theorem 1.20(a) again to obtain positive integers $m_1$ and $m_2$ such that $m_1 > nx$ and $m_2 > -nx$. Then $$-m_2 < nx < m_1. $$ Hence there is an integer $m$ (with $-m_2 \leq m \leq m_1$)  such that $$ m-1 \leq nx < m.$$ If we combine these inequalities, we obtain $$nx < m \leq 1+nx < ny.$$ Since $n > 0$, it follows that $$ x < \frac{m}{n} < y.$$ This proves Theorem 1.20(b) with $p = \frac{m}{n}$.

Now I have the following questions:

> (1) In the above proof, can we not dispense with the integers $m_1$ and $m_2$?

> (2)  How do we know that the integer $m$ satisfies the inequalities $-m_2 \leq m \leq m_1$?

> (3) As Rudin has not mentioned the well-ordering principle, how do we obtain the inequalities $ m-1 \leq nx < m$?

> (4) Is this proof sound enough logically even without using the well-ordering principle?

Comment: "How do we know that the integer $m$ satisfies ..." related: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/476689/94631

Comment: I would describe the idea of the proof as follows.  We note that if $y-x > 1$, then there must be an integer in between $x$ and $y$, and we are done.  If not, well, we can use the Archimedean principle to scale the entire real line by an integer $n$ so that $y-x$ "becomes" greater than one.  This scaling preserves rationality and gives us what we want.

Comment: Note that Rudin is a text in analysis, not foundations of mathematics.  When I studied from it, we followed the principle that we were assumed to fully understand the integers and rational numbers: any (relatively simple) arithmetic fact about them could be stated without proof.  I think the text itself follows a similar principle.  So I'm not surprised that the well-ordering of the natural numbers is used without proof or explicit mention - after all, any grade-schooler knows it (if not by that name).

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure whether Rudin was implicitly appealing to the well-ordering principle, but it is possible to interpret what he's written in a way that doesn't use it.

Namely, the set $S$ of integers that are $\leq nx$ is nonempty, by the existence of $-m_2$, which belongs to the set, and bounded above, by the existence of $m_1$, which is an upper bound for it, and does not belong to it. Therefore $S$ must have a least upper bound $p$. $p$ must belong to $S$, for otherwise $S$ would have to have two elements strictly between $p-1$ and $p$, which is impossible since the elements of $S$ are integers. Then let $m = p+1$.

The inequality $-m_2 \leq m$ follows from the fact that $p = m-1$ is the largest element of $S$, and $-m_2 \in S$. The inequality $m \leq m_1$ results from $m-1 = p \leq nx < m_1$. And the inequalities $m-1 \leq nx < m$ or, equivalently, $p \leq nx < p+1$, are a consequence of the fact that $p$ is the largest element of $S$.

I would say that this proof uses a number of unstated assumptions about the integers, their basic properties, and their relationship to the real numbers (for example, the fact that the order relation is the same, or the fact that a successor integer is obtained by adding $1$ in $\mathbf{R}$). This is unavoidable, because the integers haven't been defined. However, it does not appear that an appeal to the well-ordering principle is necessary. The proof is logically deficient only to the extent that the integers are assumed to have these unstated properties.

I don't believe the proof can be substantially improved without formalizing what the integers are, perhaps defined as a subset of $\mathbf{R}$ with certain properties, if one wishes to retain the axioms for $\mathbf{R}$ as the basis for the exposition.

Comment: I think this proof implicitly uses the well ordering property. Let R be the set of upper bounds of S. We know R is nonempty because m1 is in R. Since R is a nonempty set of integers,R must have a least element i.e. the least upper bound of S. Without this step,it's not clear how you assert that there IS a least upper bound of S-all you can show is that if S DOES have a least upper bound, it must lie in S because of your contradiction. So I can't see how you can completely eliminate the WOP from this proof no matter what version of it you take.

Comment: @Mathemagician1234 The least upper bound property of the reals is stated previously in Rudin's book, in 1.19. What I said about the set $S$ is that it is nonempty and bounded above, and therefore has a least upper bound. That step is justified by 1.19. Are you saying that apart from that, and the use of Archimedes' property, there is a use of the well-ordering property?

Comment: @Dave, I didn't get your reasoning when you state that $p$ must belong to the set $S$ of those integers which are $\leq nx$? How come $S$ would otherwise have two elements strictly between $p-1$ and $p$? How do we know this?

Comment: @SaaqibMahmuud If $p$ is the supremum, but not the maximum, of $S$, then there must be some element $r$ of $S$ between $p-1$ and $p$. (Otherwise, $p-1$ would be an upper bound for $S$, contradicting the definition of $p$.) Similarly, it can then be proved that there is an element $s$ of $S$ between $r$ and $p$.

Comment: To add to the comment by @SaaqibMahmood, I think this proof implicitly assumes that $p$ is an integer, otherwise the argument to show that $p\in S$ is not complete. This is where the well-ordering property of the integers is required.

Answer (score 2):

--> In the above proof, can we not dispense with the integers $m_1$ and $m_2$?

Yes. You can dispense with the integers $m_1$ and $m_2$, using the Lemma 1.

> **Lemma 1.** For every real number $x$ there is exactly one integer $N$ such that $N \le x < N + 1$. (This integer $N$ is called the *integer part* of $x$, and is sometimes denoted $N = \lfloor x \rfloor$.)
>
> **Lemma 2.** For any positive real number $x > 0$ there exists a positive integer $N$ such that $0 < 1/N < x$.

We now show

> **Proposition 3.** Given any two real numbers $x < y$, we can find a rational number $q$ such that $x < q < y$.

By hypothesis, we have $y -x$ is positive. So exists a positive integer $N$ such that $0 < 1/N < y - x$, by Lemma 2. Since $xN$ is a real number, by Lemma 1, there exists a integer $n$ such that $n - 1 \le xN < n$, i.e., $n/N - 1/N \le x$ and $x < n/N$. Thus $x < n/N \le x + 1/N$. Since $1/N \le y - x$, i.e., $x + 1/N < y$, we have $x < n/N < y$. Thus $n/N$ is rational, the claim follows.

--> How do we know that the integer m satisfies the inequalities $−m_2 \le m \le m_1$?

Because of $m_1, m_2$ are positive integers, we have $−m_1 < 0 < m_2$. If we add $M := m_1 - m_2$ to both sides, we obtain $-m_2 < M < m_1$. So $M$ is a integer between $-m_2$ and $m_1$. Thus you can conclude $-m_2 \le M \le m_1$. (Clearly, the equality can not be, but it is similar to: if $P$ is true, then $(P \text{ or anything})$ is true.)

--> As Rudin has not mentioned the well-ordering principle, how do we obtain the inequalities $m−1\le nx < m$?

There are many proofs about Lemma 1. You can see one of them [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/509711/interspersing-of-integers-by-reals). Also there exists a proof that does not use the well-ordering.

--> Is this proof sound enough logically even without using the well-ordering principle?

Is possible to prove the Lemma 1 without the well-ordering, by contradiction, or maybe using the induction principle.

Answer (score 1):

Basically this proof is a consequence of several successive applications of the Archimedian property. There's a slightly shorter but equivalent proof that's a little less confusing then Rudin's and it's done in 2 steps.

The first step is we have to prove if a is a real number, then there exists an integer N such that N − 1 ≤ a < N. The proof is by direct construction as follows: Let S = {n ∈ Z | n > a}. Then by the Archimedean property,S is nonempty. The set S is bounded below by a, so by the well-ordering principle,S has a least element N. Then N − 1 is not an element of S. So N-1 < a < N.

2 important observations that answers 2 of your questions: This basically gives us the result Rudin derives at the beginning, but in a little clearer manner. And it answers your question,no,we really can't dispense with this step because the main result depends on it, as you'll see. It also shows you really need the well ordering principle to derive the intermediate inequalities. Rudin tends to use a lot of "toolkit" results like the WOP without statement-it's one of the reasons he gets away with being so annoyingly concise.

Now we're ready to prove the main result. From the Archimedean property of **R** there exists q ∈ N such that 1/q < b−a. Now consider the real number qa. There exists an integer p such that p − 1 ≤ qa < p. It follows that (p−1/q) ≤ a < p/q . This gives that p/q − 1/q ≤ a, which gives that a < p/q ≤ a + 1/q < b. That completes the proof.

As I said, it's equivalent and not radically different from Rudin's, but I personally found it a little shorter and a bit easier to follow.

Comment: does this not mean that the well-ordering principle is lurking somewhere in Rudin's proof? And does this not mean that Rudin has not been thorough enough either to state this principle explicitly or any other properties of the set of integers?

Comment: @Saaqib The Well Ordering principle-or it's secret identity, the Axiom of Choice-lurks in the vast majority of mathematical proofs,particularly those involving order relations. The fact Rudin doesn't state it explicitly shows what an arrogantly poor textbook author he is. Basically,he's saying if you can't see the "obvious" facts,you're too dumb to read his book. If these facts WERE obvious, the students wouldn't need to learn analysis, would they?!? This is what mathematicians mean when they say Rudin writes his books more to prove to his peers how clever he is then to teach students.

Comment: @SaaqibMahmuud I think Rudin reasonably drew a line at the rational numbers and decided that he was not going to study the basic properties of the integers and rational numbers. Instead, taking these things as known, he presents a rigorous exposition of the properties of the real numbers. Considering that this is an analysis book, that is a reasonable choice. Some algebra books do present the integers and the rational numbers axiomatically.

Comment: @Mathemagician1234 I don't agree with your comments about Rudin's book. The problem you're talking about is specific to the context of the beginning of the book, where one may be faced with the question of assuming prerequisites on the part of the reader, such as knowledge of the integers and rational numbers.

Comment: @Dave To each his or here own. I think there are better yet equally challenging textbooks, such as Charles Chapman Pugh's or Tom Korner's.I just think Rudin is unnecessarily concise for beginners. Personally, I think it's critical for students,either as a prerequisite or concurrently, for them to study the full construction of the reals from the Peano axioms.I think only then do you really internalize the complex interrelationships that define the number systems and really understand analysis. But I also understand why that's impractical.